# How to make a wall tilemap?

Tags: python, pygame

i'm making a game but i want to make the game harder by adding walls. I found out it's called a tilemap. But it's for multiple colours, i just want one color, grey.  I want it to be something like `1,1,1,1,
1,0,0,1,
1,0,0,1,
1,1,1,1`

0 = nothing. 1 = grey rectangle. I also need it to be like `WIDTH = 16 
HEIGHT = 9
TILESIZE = dw/WIDTH`

but i can't find a way to implement it.

i tried using a def code but it lagged out my game. And i tried using this site: http://usingpython.com/pygame-tilemaps/

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*
import cv2
import time
import random
import pickle
import shutil

grey = (128,128,128)

def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    menu(1)
        screen.fill(white)
        mts("Paused", black, -100, 100)
        mts("Press esc to go back to the game or press space to go back to the menu", black, 25, 45)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

def score(score):
    text = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', 25).render("Score: "+str(score), True, black)
    screen.blit(text, [0,0])

def highscore(highscore):
    text = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', 25).render("Highscore: "+str(highscore), True, black)
    screen.blit(text, [1100,0])

#define the apple to spawn in a random place
def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, dw-at, bs)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, dh-at, bs)

    return randAppleX,randAppleY

def snake(bs, sl):
    for XnY in sl:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Dgreen, [XnY[0],XnY[1],bs,bs])

def text_objects(text,color,fontS):
    font = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', fontS)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def mts(msg,color, y_displace=0, fs=35):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,fs)
    textRect.center = (dw / 2), (dh / 2)+y_displace
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def gameLoop():
    global at
    global bs
    hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    gameHack = False
    tilemap = [
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1]
]

    WIDTH = 4 
    HEIGHT = 4
    TILESIZE = dw/WIDTH



    Speed = 20
    lead_x = dw/2
    lead_y = dh/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'music1.ogg'))
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

    slist = []
    sl = 0
    if sl > 2304:
        gameHack = True

    randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not gameExit:
        for row in range(HEIGHT):
            for column in range(WIDTH):
                if tilemap[row][column] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, grey, (column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

        while gameOver == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Game over", red, -50,100)
            mts("Press enter to play again or press space to go back to the menu", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        gameExit = False
                        gameOver = False
                        menu(1)
        while gameHack == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Hacked", red, -50,100)
            mts("You hacked or exploit the game, press enter to quit the game", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change
        prev_x, prev_y = lead_x_change, lead_y_change 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and prev_x != bs:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = -bs, 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and prev_x != -bs:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = bs, 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and prev_y != bs:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, -bs
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and prev_y != -bs:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, bs    
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and Speed >= 10 and Speed < 60:
                    Speed += 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and Speed <= 60 and Speed > 10:
                    Speed -= 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    sl += 1

        if not pygame.Rect(0, 0, dw, dh).contains(lead_x, lead_y, bs, bs):
            gameOver = True

        screen.fill(white)

        #draw the apple
        apple = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,at,at])

        sh = []
        sh.append(lead_x)
        sh.append(lead_y)
        slist.append(sh)
        snake(bs, slist)

        if len(slist) > sl:
            del slist[0]

        for eachSegment in slist[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == sh:
                gameOver = True

        score(sl)
        highscore(hs)

        if sl > hs:
            hs += 1
            os.remove( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN') )
            pickle.dump( sl, open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "wb" ) )
            hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )


        pygame.display.update()

        #make the apple spawn
        appleRect = pygame.Rect(randAppleX, randAppleY, at, at)
        if appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y):
            while True:
                randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                appleRect = pygame.Rect(randAppleX, randAppleY, at, at)
                if not appleRect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) and \
                not any(appleRect.collidepoint(*p) for p in slist):
                    break
            sl += 1
        clock.tick(Speed)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.quit()
```

I expect it to display a single color tile map, but i keep on getting crashes.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you have multiple colours, i just one color, grey.

Comment: I don't understand - you already have `for` loops to draw rectangles. What else do you need ?

Comment: if you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe then add FULL error message (full Traceback) in question.

Comment: you use `W[tilemap[row][column]]` but you don't have `W` and `tilemap`. See in your link how to create it.

Comment: K, i did it but there's no rectangles.

Comment: I don't see `W` and `tilemap` (and `MAPHEIGHT`,  `MAPWIDTH`) in code - so you can't see rectangles. But you should see error message.

Comment: what did you try? Show it in question (not in comment). We can't read in your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you have problem if you already have it in code and you have example in your link.

```
tilemap = [
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1]
]

MAPHEIGHT = 4 
MAPWIDTH = 4
TILESIZE = dw/MAPWIDTH
GREY = (128,128,128)


for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
        if tilemap[row][column] == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
```

---

**EDIT:**

You have problem because you use it in wrong place. You have to draw between `screen.fill` (which clears buffer) and `pygame.update` (which sends buffer to video card and it displays it on screen)

```
   screen.fill(white)

   for row in range(HEIGHT):
       for column in range(WIDTH):
           if tilemap[row][column] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, grey, (column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

   # ... draw other things ...       

   pygame.display.update()
```

You have mess in code. You should have

- place where you update values, move object, crate/respaw object, load/save pickle, etc. but don't draw there.
- place where you use `screen.fill`, draw all elements, use `pygame.display.update` but don't update object and don't load/save pickle

---

**EDIT:**

My version (with better names of variables and functions)

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
import random
import pickle

# --- constants --- (UPPERCASE names)

WHITE = (  0,   0,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (255,   0,   0)
GREY  = (128, 128, 128)

DISPLAY_WIDTH  = 1200
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 800

APPDATA = os.getenv('APPDATA', '')
PICKLE_PATH = os.path.join(APPDATA, 'Snake Universe', 'h.SNUN')

WIDTH  = 4
HEIGHT = 4
TILE_SIZE = DISPLAY_WIDTH/WIDTH
BLOCK_SIZE = 20

# --- functions ---

def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    menu(1)

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        mts("Paused", BLACK, -100, 100)
        mts("Press esc to go back to the game or press space to go back to the menu", BLACK, 25, 45)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

def text_object(text, color=BLACK, font_size=25):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, font_size)
    surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    rect = surface.get_rect()
    return surface, rect

def draw_score(screen, score):
    surface, rect = text_object("Score: " + str(score))
    screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))

def draw_highscore(screen, highscore):
    surface, rect = text_object("Highscore: " + str(highscore))
    screen.blit(surface, (1100, 0))

def rand_apple_pos():
    x = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
    y = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
    return x, y

def draw_snake(screen, snake):
    for x, y in snake:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (x, y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))

def mts(msg, color, y_displace=0, fs=35):
    surface, rect = text_object(msg, color, fs)
    rect.center = (DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT / 2) + y_displace
    screen.blit(surface, rect)

def game_loop(screen):
    highscore = 0

    #highscore = pickle.load(open(PICKLE_PATH, "rb" ))

    game_exit = False
    game_over = False
    game_hack = False

    speed = 10
    lead_x = DISPLAY_WIDTH/2
    lead_y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    #pygame.mixer.music.load(os.pBLOCK_SIZEh.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'music1.ogg'))
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    snake = [(100, 100)]
    score = 0

    apple_x, apple_y = rand_apple_pos()
    apple_rect = pygame.Rect(apple_x, apple_y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while not game_exit:

        while game_over == True:
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            mts("Game over", RED, -50,100)
            mts("Press enter to play again or press space to go back to the menu", BLACK, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    game_over = False
                    game_exit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        #gameLoop()
                        game_over = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        game_exit = False
                        game_over = False
                        menu(1)

        while game_hack == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            mts("Hacked", RED, -50, 100)
            mts("You hacked or exploit the game, press enter to quit the game", BLACK, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    game_over = False
                    game_exit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change
        prev_x, prev_y = lead_x_change, lead_y_change

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and prev_x != BLOCK_SIZE:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = -BLOCK_SIZE, 0

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and prev_x != -BLOCK_SIZE:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = BLOCK_SIZE, 0

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and prev_y != BLOCK_SIZE:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, -BLOCK_SIZE

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and prev_y != -BLOCK_SIZE:
                    lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, BLOCK_SIZE

                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and speed >= 10 and speed < 60:
                    speed += 10
                    clock.tick(speed)

                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and speed <= 60 and speed > 10:
                    speed -= 10
                    clock.tick(speed)

                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    score += 1

        # --- moves ---


        if not pygame.Rect(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT).contains(lead_x, lead_y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE):
            game_over = True

        if apple_rect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y):
            while True:
                apple_x, apple_y = rand_apple_pos()

                # update existing Rect without creating new Rect
                apple_rect.x = apple_x
                apple_rect.y = apple_x

                if not apple_rect.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) and \
                not any(apple_rect.collidepoint(*pos) for pos in snake):
                    break

            score += 1

        # update snake
        snake.append( (lead_x, lead_y) )
        if len(snake) > score:
            del snake[0]

        for segment in snake[:-1]:
            if segment == snake[-1]:
                game_over = True

        if score > highscore:
            #pickle.dump(score, open(PICKLE_PATH, "wb"))
            highscore = score

        if score > 2304:
            game_hack = True

        # --- draw ---

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        #draw_wall(screen)
        for row in range(HEIGHT):
            for column in range(WIDTH):
                if tilemap[row][column] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, (column*TILE_SIZE, row*TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

        draw_snake(screen, snake)

        #draw the apple
        #draw_apple(screen, apple)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, apple_rect)

        draw_score(screen, score)
        draw_highscore(screen, highscore)

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(speed)

    # --- end ---

    pygame.quit()
    sys.quit()


# --- variables ---

tilemap = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
]

HEIGHT = len(tilemap)
WIDTH = len(tilemap[0])

# --- main ---

pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_WIDTH))
game_loop(screen)
```

Comment: I get a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: so you use too big index in list. What size has `tilemap` ? What values do you have in `MAPHEIGHT` and `MAPWIDTH` ? They have to be the same as tilemap size.

Comment: i fixed it but still no rectangles. I also updated the code.

Comment: before I check code I say two things which helps me: (1) run code in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see error message (and always put full error (starting at word "Traceback") in question). (2) you can use `print()` in many places to see values in variables and see which part of code is executed (ie. `print("I'm in 'for' loop")`) - it helps to see problem (and it doesn't need to learn how to use debuger)

Comment: it print the message but not showing the rectangles

Comment: as I said - you draw in wrong place. You have to draw between `fill` and `update` which you already have in code.

Comment: see full code in asnwer. It still need to check collision with wall. It could be done in different way. You could use the same size for tile blocks and snake blocks and keep snake position as number of tail in grid, not as pixels position. Then you can check snake position in `tailmap` to get collision.